# Optimizing relation creation on large number of existing nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My cypher query for creating relations between a large batch of nodes(~1000 - 10000) looks something like the following.

```
    "MATCH (startNode1),....,(startNode1000),(endNode1),..(endNode1000)
     WHERE ID(startNode1) = 538035 AND .. ID(startNode1000) = 538035 AND ID(endNode1) = 577 ..ID(endNode1000) = 586 
     CREATE 
     (startNode1)-[r1:`ParameterValue`{Name: "Phi"}]->(endNode1),
     (startNode2)-[r2:`ParameterValue`{Type: "block"}]->(endNode2),..
     (startNode1000)-[r100:`ParameterValue`{FontAngle: "auto"}]->(endNode1000)
     RETURN ID(r1), ID(r2), ..... ID(r1000)"
```

I am using the official java neo4j bolt driver to run cypher queries and on an average the above cypher command takes about **15** seconds which is not suitable for my application.

The questions I have are:

1. Are there any obvious optimizations I am missing out by bundling my
   cypher query this way?
2. In general, is it a good practice to loop
   over the nodes to create the relation than bundling them?

I am a newbie so any suggestions are very welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any obvious optimizations I am missing out by bundling my cypher query this way?

Yes. The query in question makes the job of the query optimizer and execution engine extremely difficult. If you go to the web browser and run the query plan with [`EXPLAIN`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/#how-do-i-profile-a-query), it will show you that this query plan requires huge tuples, which is not what the engine is built to handle.

> In general, is it a good practice to loop over the nodes to create the relation than bundling them?

Looping over is a good direction. In fact, there are several optimizations that you can make:

1. Pass the collection of `[startNode, endNode, relationshipProperties]` triples as a single parameter to the driver and [`UWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/) it.
2. Use `SET relationship_variable = map_variable` [construct](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/cypher/clauses/set/#set-set-a-property-using-a-parameter) to initialize the properties of the relationship.
3. Optionally, you might want to use the [`collect`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) method to return the resulting ids in a list, but this is usually not necessary as the driver returns an iterable result.

These tricks are incorporated by this query:

```
UNWIND $rels AS rel
WITH
  rel[0] AS startNodeId,
  rel[1] AS endNodeId, 
  rel[2] AS relationshipProperties
MATCH (startNode:SomeLabel), (endNode:SomeLabel)
WHERE ID(startNode) = startNodeId
  AND ID(endNode) = endNodeId
CREATE (startNode)-[r:`ParameterValue`]->(endNode1)
SET r = relationshipProperties
WITH collect(ID(r)) AS relationshipIds
RETURN relationshipIds
```

On the client side, you should pass the parameters with the [`StatementRunner.run(statementTemplate, statementParameters)` method](http://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/StatementRunner.html#run-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-). Simply a map with a single key of `rels` and a list of three-element lists. You can express this in a concise way using a good collection library, e.g., Guava's [immutable collections](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained):

```
Map<String, Object> parameters =
  ImmutableMap.of("rels",
    ImmutableList.of(
      ImmutableList.of(1, 2, ImmutableMap.of("prop1", "value1", "prop2", false)),
      ImmutableList.of(3, 4, ImmutableMap.of(...)),
    ...
  )
);
StatementRunner.run("UNWIND ...", parameters);
```

**Note 1.** The Cypher language allows you to pass nodes and relationships as parameters. However, this only works in the embedded version and [not in the client-server setup](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10239), so you're better of passing ids.

**Note 2.** Having said that, passing internal IDs is a bad practive. While it works fine for most prototypes, you might want to consider to avoid using them and provide your own identifiers instead. See [Best and Worst Practices with Node IDs](https://neo4j.com/blog/dark-side-neo4j-worst-practices/).

**Note 3.** Instead of using triples, you can also use maps for representing the relationships-to-be-created. This way, you pass them as a Map from Java, i.e., your list will consist of maps:

```
ImmutableMap.of("startNode", 1, "endNode", 2, "relationshipProperties", ImmutableMap.of("prop1", "value1", "prop2", true))
```

Then you can refer to the values as `rel.startNode`, `rel.endNode` and `rel.relationshipProperties`. This makes the query slightly more readable and easier to maintain, but it's usually not worth the hassle.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is great information to know and I will get back to you on the performance after trying it out.

Comment: Update after implementing the solution. I was able to reduce the relationship creation time from 15 seconds to 0.2 seconds! Thank you again for the solution and other pointers as well.

Answer (score -3):

You can actually  Create the relation ship using cypher

```
MATCH (u:User {username:'admin'}), (r:Role {name:'ROLE_WEB_USER'})
CREATE (u)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(r)
```

this is just an example where we had a User node and we were creating a relation ship with a ROLE.

Here is the link to the documentation. https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create/#create-create-a-relationship-between-two-nodes

I don't think the above is correct way to do it